# Change background of button when you go to another page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, button

This might be an easy one for you, but I just can't seem to know what to search for. I'm using a CMS that doesn't have a menu that I'd like to use so I have to do it myself, but I don't know how:

I have 5 buttons that lead to other pages. When I go to page "2" I want button "2" to automatically change to another background when I click the button to it.

I figured there must be some kind of jQuery possibility to check if it's page "2" and then change the button color of that button, but I have no clue further than that.

Hopefully someone can offer me some advice. Thanks :-)

Comment: What kind of markup relationship can you establish? There has to be some unique identifier already inherit within the CMS to dictate the page, utilize that as a `data-target=""` attribute, and then do `$('button[data-target="myUniqueSelector"]').addClass('selected');`, where `.selected` contains the CSS you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that I found on a quick Google:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.primary-nav a').each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).attr('href')  ===  window.location.pathname) {
      jQuery(this).addClass('current');
    }
  });
});  
</script>
```

This assumes the nav-links are in an element with the class-name `primary-nav`, and the formatting is achieved with the class-name `current` in your css.

This works for a-tags (which have an href attribute), so it will depend how your buttons are set up. (They may be a-links that are just formatted to look like buttons.)

I searched *jquery to format current page link*

If your buttons are not a-links, but use click events to trigger some jQuery code which then changes the location of the page, then a little more work is required. You may have to give the current page link/button an id and just format this id with css. This would mean, however, that you'd have have to add this id to the relevant button in every page.